# googleVis does not display the plot after command

Tags: r, googlevis

I was trying to create a googleVis visualization plots with the following commands in R:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis)); 
      M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year", options=list(width=600, height=400));
      plot(M);
```

However, it only returns a blank web page with no content or errors. I have tried a few different browsers, but the problem persists. How can I fix it? Thanks!